# How to play Playlist in MPMoviePlayerController in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

I would like to play List of movie files(.mp4) from my application using MPMoviePlayerController. I created Player using following code, but i can see only three buttons to play, fastforward and backward. Does default MPMoviePlayerController has Previous and Next button to play next and previous video in my list. If it is avilable how can we bring those button in my controller and if is not avilable how can we achive it by customizing MPMoviePlayerController.

```
       movie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
       // movie.controlStyle =  MPMovieControlStyleNone;
          [movie setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen];
       [movie.view setFrame:CGRectMake(30, 15, 400, 250)];
       [self.view addSubview:movie.view];
       [self registerForMediaPlayerNotifications];
       [movie play];
```